# Order of growth in Levin's book

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am self-reading Levin's "[Lectures on Entire Functions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821808974)". There are two questions, I hope I they are not too much.

1) On [page 3](https://books.google.dk/books?id=fNmaAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&hl=da&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false) (bottom), the author says "If the same inequality holds for some sequence of values $r_n\to \infty$", does it mean that $h(r_n)<\phi(r_n)$ for all $n$?

2) On page 4 (above), the author says that "it follows from the definition of the order" that
$\exp(r^{\rho-\epsilon})\stackrel{n}<M_f(f)\stackrel{as}<\exp(r^{\rho+\epsilon})$ 
for every $\epsilon>0$. Why is this true?

Note: Here is $M_f(r):=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$.

-- James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h \stackrel{n} < \phi$ means by definition that there is $r_n \to \infty, h(r_n) < \phi(r_n)$ so yes you understood 1 right
Note that by the two definitions involved, the negation of $h \stackrel{as} < \phi$ is $\phi \stackrel{n} \le h$

(note that $h \stackrel{as} < \phi$ just means $h(r) < \phi (r)$ for $r \ge r_0$, where $h,\phi$ are real functions defined on the positive axis (or an infinite segment $(a,\infty)$)

For 2, by the definition of growth order, $M_f(r) \stackrel{as}<\exp(r^{\rho+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon >0$ as $\rho+\epsilon >\rho$

On the other hand, since $\rho$ is the infimum of such, we cannot have $M_f(r) \stackrel{as}<\exp(r^{\rho-\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

Hence by point 1 above, we get $\exp(r^{\rho-\epsilon}) < \exp(r^{\rho-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}) \stackrel{n} \le M_f(r)$, when we apply the above observation with $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

Comment: Thanks for your time. If I may ask, I find it interesting about your observation on the negation part. The negation part of $h\stackrel{as}<\phi$ is $\phi(r)\leq h(r)$ for some $r\geq r_0$. How does it imply that $\phi(r_n)\leq h(r_n)$ for some sequence $r_n$ diverging to infinity? Is this because picking $r_n=r$ for all $n$ would work, as this is the only existence we know?

Comment: The negation of $h\stackrel{as}<\phi$ leads to : we know there is one $r_1$, $\phi(r_1) \le h(r_1)$; but then pick $r_0=r_1+1$ and apply the negation to that $r_0$ etc - asymptotic inequality assumes both the existence of a high enough $r_0$ (depending on $h, \phi$) and the inequality after, it doesn't fixes $r_0$ for all pairs